# Java 8 ignore filter (predicate) if null

Tags: java, java-8

I have multiple predicates like

```
final Predicate<Model> predicate1 = model -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestParam1)
                && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(model.getParam1(), requestParam1);
                
final Predicate<Model> predicate2 = model -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestParam2)
                && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(model.getParam2(), requestParam2);
                
list.stream().filter(predicate1.and(predicate1)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Here both predicates apply is there any way through which i can only pass filter which is not null (i.e if requestParam1 null i don't want to add it in filter(....) same way for requestParam2)

Thank you

Comment: You could add an extra call to `filter` before your intended filter. Like this:  `.filter( Objects :: nonNull ).filter( … your predicate here … )`

Comment: Use a ternary statement maybe? something like `requestParam1 != null ? predicate_when_not_null : predicate_when_null` or use an if statement?

Comment: There is 6 or 7 predicate that i want to apply only when is null. Is there any other good way

Answer (score 1):

You could use a (static) helper function to generate such `null`-safe predicates for a given getter:

```java
class Scratch {
    class Model {
        private final String param1;
        private final String param2;

        Model(String param1, String param2) {
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
        }

        public String getParam2() {
            return param2;
        }

        public String getParam1() {
            return param1;
        }
    }
    
    public static <T> Predicate<T> startsWithIgnoreCase(Function<T, String> getter, String parameter) {
        return t -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(parameter) && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(getter.apply(t), parameter);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // example usage
        Predicate<Model> modelPredicate1 = startsWithIgnoreCase(Model::getParam1, args[0]);
        Predicate<Model> modelPredicate2 = startsWithIgnoreCase(Model::getParam2, args[1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build something like this -

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String requestParam1 = null;
        String requestParam2 = null;
        businessFunction(requestParam1, requestParam2);
    }

    public static List<Model> businessFunction(String requestParam1, String requestParam2) {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Predicate<Model> predicate = _ -> true; // not sure what the default should be, true or false

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestParam1)) {
            predicate = predicate.and(buildPredicate(Model::getParam1, requestParam1));
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestParam2)) {
            predicate = predicate.and(buildPredicate(Model::getParam2, requestParam2));
        }

        return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static Predicate<Model> buildPredicate(Function<Model, String> modelParamSupplier, String param) {
        return model -> StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(modelParamSupplier.apply(model), param);
    }

    static class Model {
        private final String param1;
        private final String param2;

        Model(String param1, String param2) {
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
        }

        public String getParam2() {
            return param2;
        }

        public String getParam1() {
            return param1;
        }
    }
}
```